# 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'type' , problem loading libraries inside a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, lib, urlopen

not sure how whould I embebed external libraries inside a class, to make it self-independant, I opted for:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 

class MyClass:
    
    from urllib.request import urlopen as LOCALurlopen
      
    LOC_baseUrl = 'https://www.someurl.com/api/'


    def resolve_API(self, myValue):

       LOC_fullRequest = self.LOC_baseUrl + '/' + myValue
       print(Loc_fullRequest)

       LOC_response = urlopen(LOC_fullRequest, timeout = 5).read()  ## works, but external dependecy

       LOC_response = self.LOCALurlopen(LOC_fullRequest, timeout = 5).read()  ## doesn't work

       print(LOC_response)
```

I made the same with other libs and works ok, but not url open, it give me the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-99-425bb23495d5> in <module>()
---> 13 printINFO(MyClass.resolve_API('anyValue'))

<ipython-input-98-dee69a279550> in resolve_API(self, myValue)
---> 55         LOC_response = self.LOCALurlopen(LOC_fullRequest, timeout = 5).read()

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    515 
    516         req.timeout = timeout
--> 517         protocol = req.type
    518 
    519         # pre-process request

AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'type'
```

how should I resolve this dependency ?

Comment: "not sure how whould I embebed external libraries inside a class, to make it self-independant," why are you doing this? It doesn't make any sense. "## works, but external dependecy" what do you mean? It is no more an external dependency than using `LOCALurlopen`... **they are the exact same object**

Comment: Putting that function in the class namespace makes it act as a method when you call it like `self.LOCALurlopen(...)`, it passes *an instance as the first argument*, like all methods. Hence the error. Just don't do this. Just use `urlopen`

Comment: then, there is no "best practice" to make the library not depedable of external dependecies, isn't it?

Comment: I mean, if my  class needs urlopen, and another plenty libraries, they are best to be load on begining of script, as general imports, than load on self library ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think load on self library does, but no, it is absolutely **not** best practice to do that. Again, it does **not** make your class any less dependent on external dependencies. It does not make your class "self independent".